# Mono vs dotnet runtime

Tags: android, .net, xamarin.android, mono, maui

According to MS sources,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/architecture
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui

*Mono* (https://github.com/mono/mono) is the **runtime** that is used for Xamarin.Forms and MAUI. As opposed to the *dotnet runtime*: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime

Therefore, when I have a system comprising of an API, and a Xamarin.Forms app, I have one application running on dotnet, on windows (.NET 6 API project) and another on Mono, on Android (.Net Standard 2.0 Xamarin.Forms).

What would be the differences in the behavior of those binaries, since they are running on different runtimes? If I have identical classes preforming **identical operations** on both projects, would there be **any potential varying behavior**, based on the fact that one is running on dotnet and the other on Mano?

As an example, I refer to this section of the Mono documentation: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/docs/exception-handling/#exceptions-throw-programmatically-from-managed-code

In here, referring to exception handling, it states:

> These exceptions are thrown from managed code using ‘throw’ or
> ‘rethrow’ CIL instructions. The JIT compiler will translate them to a
> call to a helper function called ‘mono_arch_throw/rethrow_exception’.
>
> These helper functions do not exist at compile time, they are created
> dynamically at run time by the code in the exceptions-.c files.

It explicitly refers to a function *mono_arch_throw/rethrow_exception* that does not exist in compile time, but rather **created dynamically at run time**. This type of behaviour is where the essence of my question lies. If Mono creates that function at run time, how would I know how the equivalent implementation in dotnet differs from what happens in Mono? And what are the implications of the differences in runtimes for me as a mobile app developer?

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer to "What would be the differences in the behavior of those binaries, since they are running on different runtimes?"

It depends (on what exactly is your code and what are the BCL dependencies it relies on).

There are known incompatibilities but not fully documented. If you observed some, then likely you have to develop your own workarounds (detect if the code is running with Mono and then adapt to Mono specific behaviors), since Xamarin platforms are soon-to-be deprecated and no change should be expected from Microsoft there.

### Long answer

> It's going to be a history lesson unfortunately.

At the very beginning, there were,

- Mono CLR + Mono BCL, from 2001.06 to 2014.11
- .NET Framework CLR and .NET Framework BCL

and after Microsoft made .NET Framework reference source files fully open sourced, Mono started to integrate them. And .NET Core was also added to the landscape,

- Mono CLR + Mono BCL (with many .NET Framework BCL contents), since 2014.11
- .NET Framework CLR and .NET Framework BCL
- .NET Core CLR and .NET Core BCL, since 2014.11

Microsoft/Xamarin tried very hard to keep Mono BCL/.NET Framework BCL/.NET Core BCL as close to each other as possible, but that simply isn't possible due to a variety of issues.

Xamarin products have been fully on Mono CLR + Mono BCL since day 1, so ultimately the roadmap was determined that those products will be deprecated in 2024.

All Xamarin developers have been urged to migrate to .NET MAUI, so that the MAUI apps (as well as other .NET bits you write) use .NET Core CLR + .NET Core BCL.

> There are more details omitted to keep this answer simple. For example, Mono CLR is now also part of .NET Core, so .NET Core has two CLRs, CoreCLR and Mono CLR. That's less relevant to this question.

### References

- https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin
- https://corefx.lextudio.com

Comment: On https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui#how-net-maui-works it states: "For Android, iOS, and macOS, the environment is implemented by Mono...On Windows, .NET CoreCLR...". So based on that, MAUI will also use Mono, in the same why that Xamarin.Forms used Mono as it's runtime. Or is there some important detail about that, that I'm not understanding?

Comment: @Divan if you do want some explanation on that paragraph, you need to follow my ".NET Core has two CLRs, CoreCLR and Mono CLR" part. Don't bother yourself too much on that, as Microsoft found a way to let Mono CLR and CoreCLR behave much similar in .NET 6 and above.